# How to print a loop's result horizontally with a string in python?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, output, concatenation

I want to print a loop's result horizontally with a string and a variable.

*My code*

```
total = 0
for i in range(2, 6):
    total += i
    print(i, end=' ', 'sum = {}'.format(total))
```

**The output I want:**

```
2 3 4 5 sum=14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the print of the `sum` outside the loop

```
total = 0
for i in range(2, 6):
    total += i
    print(i, end=' ')
print('sum = {}'.format(total))
```

Output

```
2 3 4 5 sum = 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the range then iterate and sum at the end

```py
r = range(2, 6)

for i in r:
    print(i, end=" ")

print(f"sum = {sum(r)}")
```

Store the range and format the string all on one line

```py
r = range(2, 6)

print(f'{" ".join([str(i) for i in r])} sum = {sum(r)}')
```

Add to the string in the loop then print at the end

```py
r = range(2, 6)

s = ""
for i in r:
    s += f"{i} "

print(f"{s}sum = {sum(r)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what Leo mentioned, you can also try to use f'{}' method to print. I find it more handy and intuitive.

```
total = 0
for i in range(2,6):
    total +=i
    print(i, ' ', end='')
print(f'sum={total}', end='')
```

Output:

```
2  3  4  5  sum=14
```